# Inputting elements of massive in sub-function and multiplying in main()

Tags: c, int, void

I must input elements of massive in sub-function, and multiplaying elements that less than max element in main() function.
For inputting elemets I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define K 70

int input_ar (int* x){
    int i;
    printf("Inputing elements of massive \n");
    for(i=0;i<K;i++){
        printf("Please, enter element %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }
}
```

For multiplying:

```
int main(){
    int x, i, mult=1;
    int max=input_ar(0);
    for(i=0;i<K;i++){
        if(input_ar(i)>max){
            max=input_ar(i);
        }
        if(input_ar(i)<max){
            mult*=input_ar(i);
        }

    }
    printf("\n Sum of elements = %d ", mult);
}
```

But I getting errors:

> [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be
>   
> [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

How can I get rid of the errors?

Comment: your `int input_ar` function not returning any value.

Comment: What exactly is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Why tag this C++? That's pure C.

Comment: What is a "massive sub-function" ?

Comment: @JensGustedt sir also notice "Inputting elements of massive" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch!:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   70

int input_ar( int *a, int n )
{
    int i = 0;

    printf( "Inputing elements of massive\n" );

    for ( ; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Please, enter element %d: ", i );
        if ( scanf( "%d", &a[i] ) != 1 ) break;
    }

    return i;
}

int max_element( const int *a, int n )
{
    int max = 0;
    int i;

    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ ) if ( a[max] < a[i] ) max = i;

    return max;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N];
    int n = input_ar( a, N );
    int max = max_element( a, n );

    int count = 0;
    int long long product = 1;
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] != a[max] )
        {
            ++count;
            product *= a[i];
        }
    }

    if ( count != 0 ) 
    {
        printf( "The product of elements "
                "that are not equal to the maximum element "
                "is %lld\n", product );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "All elements of the array are equal each other" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As for your code then it contains many errors starting from function input_ar that returns nothing and ending with string literal that says about a sum instead of the product

```
"\n Sum of elements = %d "
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `input_ar` has a parameter of type `int*`. You pass `int` values to the function. This is what the compiler is complaining about. You also should return an `int` from `input_ar` as well as `main` although it may be supplied automatically in case of `main` if you compile using C99 or C11 as seen in that standard:

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> 1. If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; <sup>11</sup> **reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0**. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>      termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Main function have to return. Make the return statement at the end of main.

```
return 0;
```

And you are defined that function taking argument as integer pointer `*x` but you are passing the value`i`. 
 So make that as like this.

```
input_ar(&i);
```

In all places. Then you placing this line,

```
mult*=input_ar(i);
```

But you are returning any thing from that function. You have to return from that function.

Comment: No, in standard C, `main` is an exception from the rule and may return just by leaving the scope.

Comment: If OP compiling with an -Wall option then it gave that warning for main function.

Comment: Then you are using a non-conforming compiler. For gcc use at least `-std=c99` or similar.